# Deserializing an ordered custom collection

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class, which has as a property a collection of instances of another class:

```
class Inventory
{
    public List<InventoryItem> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

InventoryItem has a few properties, including a DateTime Start, but I will omit its implementation for brevity.

The class above deserializes correctly out of the box, with Newtonsoft.Json:

```
string serialization = "{ 'Items': [ { 'Amount': 1, 'Start': '2018-01-14T00:00:00', 'Id': 0 } ] }";
var inventory = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Inventory>( serialization );
Assert.AreEqual( inventory.Items.First().Amount, 1 );
```

However, what I want is to sort Items, by Start, as follows:

```
class Inventory
{
    private List<InventoryItem> _inventoryItems = new();

    public List<InventoryItem> Items
    {
        // order them before returning
        get => this._inventoryItems.OrderBy( t => t.Start ).ToList();
        set => this._inventoryItems = value;
    }
}
```

Now the deserialization fails. The Inventory class is created, but no inventory items are created. I can make this work with a custom converter, but it seems to me there ought to be an easier way.

Comment: I think you may need to set `ObjectCreationHandling` to `Replace` because your getter is not returning the same object as your setter and by default `DeserializeObject` calls the getter and then modifies the object returned and never calls the setter. Alternatively you could change your getter to sort the list and set `_inventoryItems` then return `_inventoryItems`.

Comment: I can't change the ObjectCreationHandling from Auto for other reasons, but the second half of this says pretty much what Jesse says below, which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess as to what's happening here is Json.NET is setting your property to a new instance of `List<InventoryItem>` and using `Add` to add each item to the list.

In your getter, you're ordering it then using `.ToList()` to convert it back to a list. This creates a new instance of `List<InventoryItem>()`, which means the items are getting added to a different list each time, all of which are being thrown away.

However, `List<T>` does have a [`.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0) method you can utilize. Unfortunately though it returns void, so we can't make it a one-liner. In your case, the implementation of this would look a little like this:

```cs
class Inventory
{
    private List<InventoryItem> _inventoryItems = new();

    public List<InventoryItem> Items
    {
        // order them before returning
        get 
        {
            this._inventoryItems.Sort((x, y) => x.Start > y.Start ? 1 : -1);
            return this._inventoryItems;
        }
        set => this._inventoryItems = value;
    }
}
```

A little bit of an explanation on the `Sort()` method; It will always sort ascending. Returning 1 means that `x` is greater than `y`, returning -1 means that `y` is greater than `x`, and returning 0 means they're equal. In this example, it's sorting by `Start` ascending. To sort descending, you can either flip the sign or flip the values in the ternary statement.

Comment: This is exactly correct. InventoryItem already implements the default comparer I need, so simply calling this._inventoryItems.Sort() and them returning _inventoryItems does what I need. I was trying to make it a one-liner, which was why I ran into trouble.

Comment: @AaronHaspel However, it may be terribly inefficient depending on the size and distribution of the elements - the second time the getter is called, it will call `Sort` again, which could be as bad as O(n^2).

Comment: Agreed, but in this case I happen to know they're small lists (<20 items), so I can get away with it.

Comment: Even so, it's probably better to sort on the setter.

Comment: Sorting on the setter wouldn't work in this case because the items are being added with `Add()`, so they would still be out of order. It might be worth trying to create your own class that implements from `List<T>` and have it sort whenever `Add()` is called.

Comment: In practice, in production, the Items are added by creating a collection of InventoryItems and setting the Items property (via JSON, which is why I need to deserialize). Even so, Items is public, and Add() or AddRange() would screw up the sort. Sorting on the setter would be nicer and a lot more efficient, and I will consider your suggestion. Thanks to you and NetMage for the excellent suggestions.